# No HDMI output from dell latop with nvidia 1050 graphic card

Tags: hdmi, output

I've searched everywhere on the internet for find a solution to this problem, I've tried everything but still nothing work: the external monitor is connected with my laptop trought HDMI, and this is the xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080     60.13*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.07  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When I type `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1`
it gives no output, but still nothing happen.

Can somebody help me please, I'm desperate. Thanks

Comment: do you have screen output from the laptop screen?
what driver are you using? are you trying to run cuda as well?

Comment: from the laptop screen I've a normal screen output, i'm using nvidia 390 driver. I'm not trying to run cuda

Comment: so what happens when you plug in a seperate screen? it stays black? doesnt turn on or what? what shows up in system>preferences>hardware>displays menu?

Comment: it says "no hdmi input from your device. when i go in displays menu it shows only the screen of the laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally got the answer.
in the dell official website,the last site I was thinking to visite, someone resolved the same problem I had:
https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/External-Monitor-not-working-Ubuntu-nvidia/m-p/7286631#M1634

Hope this will help other people with my same problem

Comment: Lots of people have reported problems with the nVidia `418` driver you are using. +1 for this solution that hopefully helps others. Please click the grey check mark next to your answer so others know it solves the problem.