# Thunderbolt 3 dock completely locks up laptop

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, thunderbolt

I have a thunderbolt 3 dock and I'm running xubuntu 18.04. I have a similar problem to [this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113764/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-issue-with-dell-thunderbolt-3-dock-after-update), but my kernel is 4.18.0-18. I have installed the `bolt` package and I can run `boltctl list` and see my dock:

```
 o Lenovo Thunderbolt3 Graphic Dock
   |- type:          peripheral
   |- name:          Thunderbolt3 Graphic Dock
   |- vendor:        Lenovo
   |- uuid:          00cdc88c-6e42-0801-ffff-ffffffffffff
   |- status:        disconnected
   |- authorized:    Sun 28 Apr 2019 03:09:28 AM UTC
   |- connected:     Sun 28 Apr 2019 03:09:27 AM UTC
   `- stored:        Sun 28 Apr 2019 02:49:58 AM UTC
      |- policy:     auto
      `- key:        no
```

When I enable the dock (`boltctl authorize` or `enroll`) its light turns green, but then my computer freezes up completely and I need to reboot by holding the power button.

I recorded the dmesg logs when this happens and I got the following:

```
[  +0.776168] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  +0.000001] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: timeout
[  +0.000053] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1610 at /build/linux-hwe-juiyda/linux-hwe-4.18.0/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/gr/gf100.c:1524 gf100_gr_init_ctxctl_ext+0x615/0x7a0 [nouveau]
[  +0.000001] Modules linked in: nouveau(+) mxm_wmi ttm rfcomm ccm cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 arc4 wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_soc_skl kvm irqbypass snd_hda_codec_realtek crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec_generic crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress iwlmvm ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_cstate mac80211 intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep iwlwifi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc btusb snd_seq_midi btrtl snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm btbcm videobuf2_memops snd_rawmidi thinkpad_acpi btintel videobuf2_v4l2 joydev videobuf2_common bluetooth
[  +0.000029]  videodev ucsi_acpi nvram i915 input_leds snd_seq media serio_raw typec_ucsi snd_seq_device cfg80211 ecdh_generic typec wmi snd_timer snd drm_kms_helper int3403_thermal soundcore drm i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops video syscopyarea sysfillrect intel_pch_thermal sysimgblt mei_me acpi_pad processor_thermal_device mei int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 uas usb_storage nvme psmouse e1000e thunderbolt nvme_core i2c_hid hid
[  +0.000022] CPU: 0 PID: 1610 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 4.18.0-18-generic #19~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[  +0.000000] Hardware name: LENOVO 20KHCTO1WW/20KHCTO1WW, BIOS N23ET62W (1.37 ) 02/19/2019
[  +0.000026] RIP: 0010:gf100_gr_init_ctxctl_ext+0x615/0x7a0 [nouveau]
[  +0.000000] Code: ff ff 48 8b 7b 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 75 04 48 8b 5f 10 e8 4d fa 2c dd 48 89 da 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 d8 54 e8 c0 e8 fb 9e cd dc <0f> 0b b8 f0 ff ff ff e9 02 fd ff ff 48 8b 7b 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 
[  +0.000017] RSP: 0018:ffffaa9582cdb4b8 EFLAGS: 00010286
[  +0.000001] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8eedc8759e30 RCX: 0000000000000006
[  +0.000000] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff8eede14164b0
[  +0.000001] RBP: ffffaa9582cdb4e8 R08: 0000000000000561 R09: 0000000000000004
[  +0.000000] R10: ffffaa9582cdb238 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 00000000773833a0
[  +0.000001] R13: ffff8eed9a890000 R14: ffff8eedcbfac180 R15: 00000031fdbd1700
[  +0.000001] FS:  00007f6d2c552680(0000) GS:ffff8eede1400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  +0.000000] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  +0.000001] CR2: 00007f8c389d14b0 CR3: 000000046c7b0005 CR4: 00000000003606f0
[  +0.000001] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  +0.000000] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  +0.000000] Call Trace:
[  +0.000023]  gf100_gr_init_ctxctl+0x222/0x2c0 [nouveau]
[  +0.000018]  gf100_gr_init+0x563/0x590 [nouveau]
[  +0.000017]  gf100_gr_init_+0x5b/0x60 [nouveau]
[  +0.000019]  nvkm_gr_init+0x1d/0x20 [nouveau]
[  +0.000014]  nvkm_engine_init+0x6b/0x200 [nouveau]
[  +0.000015]  nvkm_subdev_init+0xb9/0x200 [nouveau]
[  +0.000014]  nvkm_engine_ref.part.0+0x4a/0x70 [nouveau]
[  +0.000012]  nvkm_engine_ref+0x13/0x20 [nouveau]
[  +0.000012]  nvkm_ioctl_new+0x27b/0x2c0 [nouveau]
[  +0.000021]  ? nvkm_fifo_chan_dtor+0xf0/0xf0 [nouveau]
[  +0.000019]  ? gf100_gr_chsw_load+0x50/0x50 [nouveau]
[  +0.000013]  nvkm_ioctl+0x11d/0x280 [nouveau]
[  +0.000021]  nvkm_client_ioctl+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
[  +0.000013]  nvif_object_ioctl+0x47/0x50 [nouveau]
[  +0.000013]  nvif_object_init+0xc8/0x120 [nouveau]
[  +0.000021]  nvc0_fbcon_accel_init+0x5c/0x920 [nouveau]
[  +0.000019]  nouveau_fbcon_create+0x4cd/0x600 [nouveau]
[  +0.000007]  ? drm_setup_crtcs+0x237/0xaa0 [drm_kms_helper]
[  +0.000003]  __drm_fb_helper_initial_config_and_unlock+0x1c5/0x400 [drm_kms_helper]
[  +0.000003]  drm_fb_helper_initial_config+0x35/0x40 [drm_kms_helper]
[  +0.000018]  nouveau_fbcon_init+0x13c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
[  +0.000019]  nouveau_drm_load+0x18b/0x7f0 [nouveau]
[  +0.000003]  ? sysfs_do_create_link_sd.isra.2+0x70/0xb0
[  +0.000012]  drm_dev_register+0x128/0x1b0 [drm]
[  +0.000005]  drm_get_pci_dev+0x93/0x170 [drm]
[  +0.000018]  nouveau_drm_probe+0x1eb/0x270 [nouveau]
[  +0.000003]  local_pci_probe+0x47/0xa0
[  +0.000001]  pci_device_probe+0x145/0x1b0
[  +0.000003]  driver_probe_device+0x2ff/0x480
[  +0.000001]  __driver_attach+0xe3/0x110
[  +0.000001]  ? driver_probe_device+0x480/0x480
[  +0.000001]  ? driver_probe_device+0x480/0x480
[  +0.000001]  bus_for_each_dev+0x74/0xb0
[  +0.000002]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1b0/0x1c0
[  +0.000001]  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
[  +0.000001]  bus_add_driver+0x167/0x260
[  +0.000001]  ? 0xffffffffc0f3c000
[  +0.000001]  driver_register+0x60/0x100
[  +0.000001]  ? 0xffffffffc0f3c000
[  +0.000001]  __pci_register_driver+0x5a/0x60
[  +0.000017]  nouveau_drm_init+0x18d/0x1000 [nouveau]
[  +0.000003]  do_one_initcall+0x4a/0x1c9
[  +0.000002]  ? __vunmap+0x8e/0xc0
[  +0.000002]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x40
[  +0.000001]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xb8/0x1c0
[  +0.000002]  ? do_init_module+0x27/0x209
[  +0.000001]  do_init_module+0x5f/0x209
[  +0.000002]  load_module+0x1930/0x1f60
[  +0.000002]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xfc/0x120
[  +0.000001]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xfc/0x120
[  +0.000002]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
[  +0.000001]  do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x120
[  +0.000001]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[  +0.000001] RIP: 0033:0x7f6d2c06e839
[  +0.000000] Code: 00 f3 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 1f f6 2c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 
[  +0.000017] RSP: 002b:00007ffd4408c1c8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[  +0.000001] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055a4c2cea3c0 RCX: 00007f6d2c06e839
[  +0.000001] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f6d2bd4d145 RDI: 0000000000000010
[  +0.000000] RBP: 00007f6d2bd4d145 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007ffd4408c2e0
[  +0.000001] R10: 0000000000000010 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[  +0.000000] R13: 000055a4c2cd7a80 R14: 0000000000020000 R15: 000055a4c2cea3c0
[  +0.000001] ---[ end trace 1679d7b34917436c ]---
[  +0.000005] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
[  +0.044732] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: DRM: allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x200000, bo 000000003c2efb08
[  +0.000945] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: fb1: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[  +0.000030] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:0a:00.0 on minor 1
[  +0.065965] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  +0.000001] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  +0.040018] cdc_ether 6-2.4.1:2.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:0b:00.0-2.4.1, CDC Ethernet Device, 30:9c:23:f3:05:03
[  +0.165079] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: i2c: aux 0004: begin idle timeout bad00100
[  +0.339924] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: i2c: aux 0005: begin idle timeout bad00100
[  +0.016385] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[  +0.048284] cdc_ether 6-2.4.1:2.0 enx309c23f30503: renamed from eth0
[  +0.227093] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[  +0.013650] input: Generic USB Audio Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:01.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:04.0/0000:0b:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.4/5-2.4.2/5-2.4.2:1.3/0003:17EF:3064.0001/input/input20
[  +0.035393] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: i2c: aux 0006: begin idle timeout bad00100
[  +0.029965] input: Generic USB Audio as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:01.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:04.0/0000:0b:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.4/5-2.4.2/5-2.4.2:1.3/0003:17EF:3064.0001/input/input21
[  +0.000201] hid-generic 0003:17EF:3064.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Generic USB Audio] on usb-0000:0b:00.0-2.4.2/input3
[  +0.083019] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx309c23f30503: link is not ready
[  +0.302256] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: i2c: aux 0004: begin idle timeout bad00100
[  +0.341230] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: i2c: aux 0005: begin idle timeout bad00100
[  +0.341531] nouveau 0000:0a:00.0: i2c: aux 0006: begin idle timeout bad00100
[  +0.134998] thinkpad_acpi: undocked from hotplug port replicator
[  +2.039132] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

The whole log is [here](https://pastebin.com/VXLNd7Mh).

Comment: Thunderbolt 3 is constantly being improved. A new kernel might help you out. You are already getting a boot warning message about your version `4.18`. Also your graphics card seems to have problems with Nouveau driver. You could try nVidia proprietary drivers instead.

Comment: Okay, I've upgraded to xubuntu 19.04 and kernel v5.0.0-13. It doesn't lock up anymore, but I haven't tested anything yet.

Comment: I installed the nvidia drivers and the graphics card is detected now. However, I can't get the connected displays to work. They show up in xrandr but I can't enable them, which I think has something to do with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515994/nvidia-x-server-settings-only-shows-1-screen-laptop-external-monitor-connecte).

Comment: If you installed nVidia driver version `418` which appears plagued, although not the same issue read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138615/no-hdmi-output-from-dell-latop-with-nvidia-1050-graphic-card/1138909#comment1887442_1138909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was:

1. Install regular Ubuntu (19.04 with kernel `5.0.0-13`)
2. Manually install the NVIDIA driver: `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`
3. Reboot
4. Check the graphics card is detected by running `nvidia-smi`
5. Install the [eGPU switcher](https://egpu.io/forums/thunderbolt-linux-setup/ubuntu-19-04-easy-to-use-setup-script-for-your-egpu/) [GitHub](https://github.com/hertg/egpu-switcher)
6. Reboot

This approach *might* work with Xubuntu. I'm not sure if the eGPU switcher works completely with xfce.